# JSON nested array Sum values with key

Tags: mysql, multidimensional-array, mysql-json, json-extract

My table structure in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `user_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `data` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`data`))
)
```

Table data

| id | user | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | {"box1": {"books": 12, "pen": 100},"box2": {"books": 13, "pen": 200},"box4": {"books": 17, "pen": 300},"box5": {"books": 16, "pen": 300}} |
| 2 | 5 | {"box1": {"books": 12, "pen": 100},"box2": {"books": 13, "pen": 200},"box3": {"books": 14, "pen": 300}} |

My expected results:

| box | books | pen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| box1 | 24 | 200 |
| box2 | 26 | 400 |
| box3 | 14 | 300 |
| box4 | 17 | 300 |
| box5 | 16 | 300 |

What is the MySQL select query to get this result?

Comment: Directly using an SQL this does not seem to be possible. If you are using MySQL that supports JSON functions, then you can alter your table and make `data` column of type `JSON` instead of a `longtext`. Then you can try some JSON functions available in MySQL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html.  Still it seems a bit unlikely to do the exact thing that you want to do in the given JSON structure. I.e. group by on the keys of JSON.  There is `JSON_KEYS` function which will give you an array of keys, but not sure how to group & then sum on the inner keys as well

Comment: You provide 2 datatables. What is sample data and what is desired output? Also - provide sample data not as a table but as INSERT INTO. Also - provide precise MySQL version. And why you use LONGTEXT datatype instead of JSON?

Comment: If you are using MySQL >= 8.0.4 you can use [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table), here [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0XEzEzNR) for ideas.